# Can't show soft keyboard when EditText at the bottom of recyclerView is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here's my problem: I have an RecyclerView which contains a lot of editText.
When I click on the editText at the end of the recycler my soft keyboard shows and then hide instantly. (I think it may be because the soft keyboard would hide the editText).

I set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

In my activity and it didn't solve my problem.

I also tried to

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerView.size() - 1);
```

But it didn't work either.

Here's the xml code of my recyclerView

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/message_editor_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_lightest"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        />
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: post your xml code for recylerview

Comment: You can try with another keyboard application to investigate better